# jTable and SQL Data retrieve

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

[image]

First post, If I made a mistake please forgive me!

On my jTable "ID", "Name" values from the database show up but the "balance" doesn't!

What's the reason?

Here's the source code :

```
    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Tools.setCenter(this);

        DAL d = new DAL();

        Object[][] Customer = d.select("select * from customer");

        String[] column = {"ID", "Name", "Balance"};

        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable(Customer, column);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    }                                 

    private void jTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        if (evt.getKeyCode() == 27) {

            this.setVisible(false);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code of the `select` method .

Comment: Have you debugged to see whether Customer Object have balance value?

Comment: @Berger post `select * from customer` result please

Comment: '19', 'Noorullah', '200'
'21', 'See Ya', '100'
'25', 'Yousef', '100'
'26', 'Ahmad', '100'
'27', 'Asad', '100'
'28', 'Shams', '100'
'29', 'Nematullah', '100'

Comment: Are you sure that column name is `Balance`?

Comment: First value is "ID" Second "Name" third "Balance"

Comment: Please post the content of `Customer ` object, something is mising

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Let me out it this way, I have a table named "customer"  it has "customer_id"  "customer_name" and "balance"

Comment: As you guy can see in the picture, I can bring customer_id and customer_name on jTable but the numbers in balance column of the database dosent show up on the jTable

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioning the exact code needed!!
Hope that you have created table with 3 columns..
Try this code

```
ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from customer");
rs=ps.exectuteQuery();
while(rs.next()) 
{
int row=0;
for(int i=1,i<=rsmd.getColumnCount();i++)
{   
jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString(i),row,i-1);
}
row=row+1; 
}
```